# inserting a new node on a linked list creates a new one

Tags: c, linux, pointers, unix, linked-list

i'm trying to create a linked list, which creates fine but when i try to insert new nodes to the already non-empty list and display it, only the new inserted node exist. here's the code:

```
struct patient{
  char name[NAME];
  int ttime;
  int atime;
  int priority;
  struct patient *next;
};

struct wr{
  struct patient *fnode;
  struct patient *lnode;
}*wr;

void wr_insert(struct patient *node){
  if(wr->fnode == NULL){
    wr->fnode = node;
    wr->lnode = node;
  }

  else{

    wr->lnode->next = node;

    wr->lnode = node;

  }

}
void display(){
  struct patient *tmp = wr->fnode;
  while(tmp != NULL){
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n",tmp->name,tmp->ttime,tmp->atime,tmp->priority);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}
    void new_patient(char *line){
      int i,check;
      listsem = sem_open(lISTSEM, 0);
      char *token;
      token = strtok(line," ");
      check = atoi(token);
      if(check == 0){
        struct patient *node = malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
        strcpy(node->name,token);
        node->ttime = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        node->atime = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        node->priority = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        node->next = NULL;
        sem_wait(listsem);
        wr_insert(node);
        sem_post(listsem);
      }
      else{
        struct patient *group = malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
        sprintf(group->name,"20171201-%d",groupnum);
        group->ttime = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        group->atime = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        group->priority = atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
        group->next = NULL;
        groupnum++;
        sem_wait(listsem);
        wr_insert(group);
        sem_post(listsem);
        for(i=1;i<check;i++){
          struct patient *node = malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
          sprintf(node->name,"20171201-%d",groupnum);
          node->ttime = group->ttime;
          node->atime = group->atime;
          node->priority = group->priority;
          node->next = NULL;
          groupnum++;
          sem_wait(listsem);
          wr_insert(node);
          sem_post(listsem);
        }
        display();
      }
      get_patient();
    }
```

So for example, if i input through the pipe `"3 10 20 30"` it rightfully displays the 3 nodes i've created. However if i do it again, when it should print 6 nodes, it only prints 3 again, but the new ones.

Comment: The head of your list is getting nulled out between calls.  Your code is too messy/I don't use C often enough to give a more focused answer.  The correction is to preserve the head between calls.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could you point out where the head is being nulled out? Also is the code messy specifically because of the linked list part or the new_patient function? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use a debugger. it will tell you where you made an error in your thoughts (and hence a bug in your program).

Comment: Tell us how you are making the two sets of calls to add 3 nodes each.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's like i said in the post. That `3 10 20 30`. the 3 means it's going to be created 3 individual nodes with the information 10,20,30. And using it through a named pipe.

Answer (score 0):

this struct definition/instance:

```
struct wr
{
    struct patient *fnode;
    struct patient *lnode;
} *wr;
```

is not correct, because the root pointers are fine, but the the instance of `wr` needs to be an instance of the struct, not a pointer to an instance of the struct.

Suggest:

```
struct wr
{
    struct patient *fnode;
    struct patient *lnode;
} wr;
```

then the rest of the code needs to treat `wr` as an instance of the struct and not a pointer to the struct  So this:

```
void wr_insert(struct patient *node)
{
     if(wr->fnode == NULL)
     {
         wr->fnode = node;
         wr->lnode = node;
     }

     else
     {
         wr->lnode->next = node;
         wr->lnode = node;
     }
```

should be:

```
void wr_insert(struct patient *node)
{
     if(wr.fnode == NULL)
     {
         wr.fnode = node;
         wr.lnode = node;
     }

     else
     {
         wr.lnode->next = node;
         wr.lnode = node;
     }
```